# Log4perl inside a package with custom appender filename

Tags: perl, log4perl

I would like to use Log4perl inside a package to log messages to a *custom filename* and to the screen.

My mail file `test.pl`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use lib '.';
use MyPackage;

helloWorld();
```

My package file `MyPackage.pm`:

```perl
package MyPackage;
use Exporter;

our @ISA= qw( Exporter );
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( helloWorld );
our @EXPORT = qw( helloWorld );

sub getLogFileName { return "log.txt"; }

my $log_conf = q(
  log4perl.logger = ALL, App, Screen

  log4perl.appender.App          = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
  log4perl.appender.App.filename = sub { return getLogFileName(); }
  log4perl.appender.App.layout   = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
  log4perl.appender.App.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p %l %m%n

  log4perl.appender.Screen        = Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen
  log4perl.appender.Screen.stderr = 0
  log4perl.appender.Screen.layout = Log::Log4perl::Layout::SimpleLayout
);

use Log::Log4perl;
Log::Log4perl::init(\$log_conf);
my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger("MyPackage");

sub helloWorld {
    $logger->trace('this is a TRACE message');
    $logger->debug('this is a DEBUG message');
    $logger->info('this is an INFO message');
    $logger->warn('this is a WARN message');
    $logger->error('this is an ERROR message');
    $logger->fatal('this is a FATAL message');
}

1;
```

Running `test.pl` prints out the following error:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::getLogFileName called at (eval 6) line 1.
Compilation failed in require at ./test.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./test.pl line 4.
```

- If I place the same package code inside `test.pl`, it works fine.
- If I place a hard-coded filename in `log_conf` inside `MyPackage.pm`, it works fine.

Any suggestions on how to fix the error?

Comment: Not familiar with log4perl, but you might have to fully qualify the function call? `return MyPackage::getLogFileName();`?

Comment: I recommend trying `log4perl.appender.App.filename = sub { return MyPackage::getLogFileName(); }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```perl
sub { return getLogFileName(); }
```

This subroutine is, based on the error message, evaluated and executed in the scope of the `main` package, where there is no `getLogFileName()` subroutine. Using a fully qualified name instead like

```perl
sub { return MyPackage::getLogFileName(); }
```

will allow it to call the intended function.